# Streaming through .NET application in Azure

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-pig, azure-storage, azure-hdinsight

I have a .NET executable through which I want to stream data in Pig on my Azure HDInsight cluster. I've uploaded it to my container, but when I try to stream data through it, I get the following error:

```
<line 1, column 393> Failed to generate logical plan. Nested exception: java.io.IOException: Invalid ship specification: '/util/myStreamApp.exe' does not exist!
```

I define and use my action as follows:

```
DEFINE myApp `myStreamApp.exe` SHIP('/util/myStreamApp.exe');
outputData = STREAM inputData THROUGH myApp;
```

I try with and without the leading /, tried qualifying as `wasb:///util/myStreamApp.exe` and tried fully qualifying it as `wasb://myContainer@myAccount.blob.core.windows.net/util/myStreamApp.exe`, but in every case, I get the message that my file doesn't exist.

[This page on uploading to HDInsight](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-upload-data/#commandline) indicates you can use the Azure Blob Storage path of `wasb:///example/data/davinci.txt` in HDInsight as `/example/data/davinci.txt`, which indicates to me that there shouldn't be a problem with the paths.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was that I wasn't declaring a dependency on the caller's side. I've got a console app that creates the Pig job:

```
var job = new PigJobCreateParameters()
{
    Query = myPigQuery,
    StatusFolder = myStatusFolder
};
```

But I needed to add to the `job.Files` collection a dependency upon my file:

```
job.Files.Add("wasbs://myContainer@myAccount.blob.core.windows.net/util/myStreamApp.exe");
```